# Greek works no longer with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, greek

Since two or three days I can't write Greek with `LuaTeX` using `\textgreek` and `\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}`. I have absolutely no idea why this is so -- it *did* work until now.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,greek,english,french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures=TeX,%
                                     ItalicFont = GFSPorson-Regular,%
                                     SmallCapsFont = GFSPorson-Regular]
\begin{document}
\emph{emphblabla}\textgreek{Ζεύς}{\greektext Ζεύς}\textit{textitbla}

{\itshape itshapebla Ζεύς}

\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
  Ζεύς οτηερλανγυαγε
\end{otherlanguage}

{\selectlanguage{greek}\selectfont Ζεύς σελεψτλανγυαγε}
{\setmainfont{GFSPorson} Ζεύς} %only this works
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem is twofold: on the one hand `babel-greek` seems to have issues with LuaLaTeX, on the other hand TeX Gyre Pagella has limited support for Greek (no ύ, for instance).

Comment: On the second point: That's why I use -- or used until now -- GFS Porson. It lacks the digamma, which is not at issue here.

Comment: With `polyglossia` everything seems to be fine in XeLaTeX (except `greektext`)... with babel I have problem and I confirm that the problem is not just LuaLatex specific. (I tried with `english` and `greek` languages only and with `TeX Gyre Pagella` as main font)... It seems to be a babel problem. Also, may be related is that babel needs `xltxtra` to recognize `\setmainfont` command. I would suggest you to work with pollyglossia if it is available in LuaLatex and contains all your used languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't claim that your code never worked. A number of things relevant changed in the format (the font encoding), babel and fontspec.

But in a current system it is not meant to work. \textgreek is according to the documentation only defined when pdflatex and LGR encoding is used. So if you want it, you will have to define it yourself, similar for \greektext.

Imho you don't really need luatextra nowadays (it is from 2010).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,greek,english,french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}


\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}

\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures=TeX,%
                                     ItalicFont = GFSPorson-Regular,%
                                     SmallCapsFont = GFSPorson-Regular]

\addto\extrasgreek{\greekfont}

\newcommand\textgreek[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}


\begin{document}
blblb {\itshape itshapebla Ζεύς}

\textgreek{Ζεύς}{\greekfont Ζεύς}\textit{textitbla}


\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
  Ζεύς οτηερλανγυαγε
\end{otherlanguage}

{\selectlanguage{greek}Ζεύς σελεψτλανγυαγε}   

blblbl blblb 


\end{document}
```

[image]